# Update Django Model With Form Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to update the quantity of my Inventory model using a Integer form field on the front end. I am able to add a new inventory item, but I want to update existing items. Here is my code:

FROM VIEWS.PY

```
def view_inventory(request, slug):

if request.method == 'POST':
    quantity_add = addQuantity(request.POST)
    if quantity_add.is_valid():
        cd = quantity_add.cleaned_data
        addq=Inventory(quantity = cd.get('quantity'))
        addq.save()

quantity_add=addQuantity()

return render(request, 'inv/view_inventory.html', {
    'item': get_object_or_404(Inventory.objects.all(), slug=slug),
    'form' : quantity_add,
    })
```

FROM MODELS.PY

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_inventory', None, { 'slug' : self.slug })

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

FROM URLS.PY

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'inv.views.view_inventory', name='view_inventory'),
```

Comment: what is the question? do you get any error, what happens? Also please post `addQuantity` form definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to get the record and then update it:

```
 def view_inventory(request, slug):

  if request.method == 'POST':
        quantity_add = addQuantity(request.POST)
        if quantity_add.is_valid():
            cd = quantity_add.cleaned_data
            old_inventory = Inventory.objects.get(id=something here) #id or pk or whatever you want
            old_inventory.quantity = cd.get('quantity')
            old_inventory.save()

    quantity_add=addQuantity()

    return render(request, 'inv/view_inventory.html', {
        'item': get_object_or_404(Inventory.objects.all(), slug=slug),
        'form' : quantity_add,
        })
```